# Swift: Recursive use of generic struct

Tags: swift, linked-list

I'm playing around with linked lists in Swift and I'm using:

```
struct Node<Element> {
    var next: Node<Element>? 
}
```

it yields this error:

```
Recursive value type "Node<Element>" is not allowed.
```

I tried using indirect on both the struct declaration and the property but neither worked. How do you implement this type of structure?

Answer (score 3):

When you write `var next: Node<Element>?`, Swift tries to put this storage inline, but since it's recursive, that results in an infinite-size struct.

`indirect` only applies to enums, so you could do something like this:

```
enum Node<Element> {
    indirect case Node(Element, next: Node?)
}

Node.Node(42, next: nil)
```

Or you can use a regular reference type, a.k.a. `class`:

```
class Node<Element> {
    var next: Node<Element>?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that is not possible to create a recursive use of struct, but you can do by using `enum`, associated values and the `indirect` attribute.

> A recursive enumeration is an enumeration that has another instance of
>   the enumeration as the associated value for one or more of the
>   enumeration cases. You indicate that an enumeration case is recursive
>   by writing indirect before it, which tells the compiler to insert the
>   necessary layer of indirection.

```
indirect enum Tree<Element: Comparable> {
    case Empty
    case Node(Tree<Element>,Element,Tree<Element>)
}
```

Code taken from [AirspeedVelocity](http://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/07/22/a-persistent-tree-using-indirect-enums-in-swift/).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with Structs. It's also doesn't seem wise to do linked list with value types. Unless you feel like doing

```
head.next.next.next.next.next = head.next.next.next.next.next.next
```

to delete the seventh node, you're going to want to be able to set

```
let next = head.next
```